# Count number of valid rows in XML

Tags: xml, xslt, counter, increment

I've been trying to convert an xml to html that will put the XML into a HTML table.

I have the following XML:

```
<services>
    <service>
        <name>Acupuncture</name>
        <benefits>
            <period>Previous 6 months</period>
            <amount>40</amount>
        </benefits>
        <benefits>
            <period>Current 6 months</period>
            <amount>60</amount>
        </benefits>
    </service>
    <service>
        <name>Artificial Aids</name>
        <benefits>
            <period>Previous 6 months</period>
            <amount>0</amount>
        </benefits>
        <benefits>
            <period>Current 6 months</period>
            <amount>0</amount>
        </benefits>
    </service>
    <service>
        <name>Chiropractic and Osteopathy</name>
        <benefits>
            <period>Previous 6 months</period>
            <amount>100</amount>
        </benefits>
        <benefits>
            <period>Current 6 months</period>
            <amount>25</amount>
        </benefits>
    </service>
    <service>
        <name>Major Dental</name>
        <benefits>
            <period>Previous 6 months</period>
            <amount>1125</amount>
        </benefits>
        <benefits>
            <period>Current 6 months</period>
            <amount>0</amount>
        </benefits>
    </service>
    <service>
        <name>General Dental</name>
        <benefits>
            <period>Previous 6 months</period>
            <amount>75</amount>
        </benefits>
        <benefits>
            <period>Current 6 months</period>
            <amount>23</amount>
        </benefits>
    </service>
    <service>
        <name>Dietetics</name>
        <benefits>
            <period>Previous 6 months</period>
            <amount>0</amount>
        </benefits>
        <benefits>
            <period>Current 6 months</period>
            <amount>0</amount>
        </benefits>
    </service>
    <service>
        <name>Health Management</name>
        <benefits>
            <period>Previous 6 months</period>
            <amount>150</amount>
        </benefits>
        <benefits>
            <period>Current 6 months</period>
            <amount>0</amount>
        </benefits>
    </service>
    <service>
        <name>Hearing Aids</name>
        <benefits>
            <period>Previous 6 months</period>
            <amount>90</amount>
        </benefits>
        <benefits>
            <period>Current 6 months</period>
            <amount>1050</amount>
        </benefits>
    </service>
    <service>
        <name>Natural Therapies</name>
        <benefits>
            <period>Previous 6 months</period>
            <amount>0</amount>
        </benefits>
        <benefits>
            <period>Current 6 months</period>
            <amount>0</amount>
        </benefits>
    </service>
    <service>
        <name>Occupational Therapy</name>
        <benefits>
            <period>Previous 6 months</period>
            <amount>0</amount>
        </benefits>
        <benefits>
            <period>Current 6 months</period>
            <amount>0</amount>
        </benefits>
    </service>
    <service>
        <name>Optical</name>
        <benefits>
            <period>Previous 6 months</period>
            <amount>375</amount>
        </benefits>
        <benefits>
            <period>Current 6 months</period>
            <amount>0</amount>
        </benefits>
    </service>
    <service>
        <name>Gym</name>
        <benefits>
            <period>Lifetime</period>
            <amount>2500</amount>
        </benefits>
    </service>
    <service>
        <name>Pharmacy</name>
        <benefits>
            <period>Previous 6 months</period>
            <amount>0</amount>
        </benefits>
        <benefits>
            <period>Current 6 months</period>
            <amount>0</amount>
        </benefits>
    </service>
    <service>
        <name>Physiotherapy</name>
        <benefits>
            <period>Previous 6 months</period>
            <amount>15</amount>
        </benefits>
        <benefits>
            <period>Current 6 months</period>
            <amount>30</amount>
        </benefits>
    </service>
    <service>
        <name>Podiatry</name>
        <benefits>
            <period>Previous 6 months</period>
            <amount>0</amount>
        </benefits>
        <benefits>
            <period>Current 6 months</period>
            <amount>0</amount>
        </benefits>
    </service>
    <service>
        <name>Psychology</name>
        <benefits>
            <period>Previous 6 months</period>
            <amount>0</amount>
        </benefits>
        <benefits>
            <period>Current 6 months</period>
            <amount>0</amount>
        </benefits>
    </service>
    <service>
        <name>Remedial Massage</name>
        <benefits>
            <period>Previous 6 months</period>
            <amount>0</amount>
        </benefits>
        <benefits>
            <period>Current 6 months</period>
            <amount>0</amount>
        </benefits>
    </service>
    <service>
        <name>Speech Therapy</name>
        <benefits>
            <period>Previous 6 months</period>
            <amount>0</amount>
        </benefits>
        <benefits>
            <period>Current 6 months</period>
            <amount>0</amount>
        </benefits>
    </service>
</services>
```

I'm trying to convert it to a table and leave out the services that have "0" values for the past 6 and current 6 months and I want to display the *Gym* service as a separate column that spans to the valid rows.

I have the following XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="html"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="selectNew">
      <xsl:value-of select="count(/services/service/benefits[1][amount !='0'] |/services/service/benefits[2][amount !='0'] )  -1"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="GymCost">
      <xsl:for-each select="/services/service">
        <xsl:if test="name/text()='Gym'">
          <xsl:value-of select="benefits[1]/amount"/>
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
    <html>
      <body>
        <table border="1" width="100%">
          <xsl:for-each select="/services/service">
            <xsl:if test="not ( benefits[2]/amount/text()='0' and benefits[1]/amount/text()='0') ">
              <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
                <tr>
                  <td style="text-align:center"> Name </td>
                  <td style="text-align:center">Past 6 Months</td>
                  <td style="text-align:center">Current 6 Months</td>
                  <td style="text-align:center"> Gym </td>
                </tr>
              </xsl:if>
              <tr>
                <xsl:if test="not(/name/text()='Gym')">
                  <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <xsl:if test="not(benefits[2]/amount/text()='0')">
                      <xsl:value-of select="benefits[2]/amount"/>
                    </xsl:if>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <xsl:if test="not(benefits[1]/amount/text()='0')">
                      <xsl:value-of select="benefits[1]/amount"/>
                    </xsl:if>
                  </td>
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
                  <td rowspan="$selectNew"><xsl:value-of select="$GymCost"/>  .. <xsl:value-of select="$selectNew"/>
        </td>
                </xsl:if>
              </tr>
            </xsl:if>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But I having difficulties displaying the *Gym* column to span to the correct number of valid rows display in the table.

Current Output
[image: Current Output Screenshot]

Can someone please direct me on how I can count the valid number of rows so I can display the Gym column correctly?

Desired Output where *Gym* Column spans in 9 rows

[image: Desired Output Screenshot]

Comment: The Gym column is only valid for the entire service, so it will show only one column for the whole "Service".

Comment: The output can be found here
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ijtc.jpg

Comment: Thanks, in this example the desired output is the Gym Column to span into 9 rows, 

The desired output is in here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTzgI.jpg

I just hard coded the there

Comment: Where does 13 come from? Shouldn't it be 9 per the row span? This is the count of services where past/current amounts > 0.

Answer (score 0):

First, your `selectNew` variable should be:

```
<xsl:variable name="selectNew" >
    <xsl:value-of select="count(/services/service[
        benefits[1][amount != 0] or benefits[2][amount != 0]
        ])" />
</xsl:variable>
```

that is counting the service nodes having at least 1 descendant `amount` node that is not equal to zero.

Second, you should use the attribute value templates, instead of this:

```
<xsl:if test ="position() = 1">  
    <td rowspan="$selectNew">  
        <xsl:value-of select="$GymCost"/>  .. <xsl:value-of select="$selectNew"/>
    </td>
</xsl:if>
```

you should use this:

```
<xsl:if test ="position() = 1">  
    <td rowspan="{$selectNew}">  
        <xsl:value-of select="$GymCost"/>  .. <xsl:value-of select="$selectNew"/>
    </td>
</xsl:if>
```

Maybe you forgot to include the braces in there.

The whole stylesheet is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="html"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="selectNew" >
            <xsl:value-of select="count(/services/service[benefits[1][amount != 0] or benefits[2][amount != 0]])" />
        </xsl:variable> 

        <xsl:variable name="GymCost" >
            <xsl:for-each select="/services/service">
                <xsl:if test="name/text()='Gym'">   
                    <xsl:value-of select="benefits[1]/amount"/>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:variable>

        <html>
            <body>
                <table border="1" width="100%">
                    <xsl:for-each select="/services/service">
                        <xsl:if test="not ( benefits[2]/amount/text()='0' and benefits[1]/amount/text()='0') ">
                            <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
                                <tr> <td style="text-align:center"> Name </td> <td style="text-align:center">Past 6 Months</td> <td style="text-align:center">Current 6 Months</td> <td style="text-align:center"> Gym </td> </tr>
                            </xsl:if>  
                            <tr>
                                <xsl:if test="not(/name/text()='Gym')">   

                                    <td> 
                                        <xsl:value-of select="name"/> 
                                    </td> 
                                    <td>               
                                        <xsl:if test="not(benefits[2]/amount/text()='0')">   
                                            <xsl:value-of select="benefits[2]/amount"/>
                                        </xsl:if>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <xsl:if test="not(benefits[1]/amount/text()='0')">   
                                            <xsl:value-of select="benefits[1]/amount"/>
                                        </xsl:if>
                                    </td>

                                </xsl:if>
                                <xsl:if test ="position() = 1">  
                                    <td rowspan="{$selectNew}">  
                                        <xsl:value-of select="$GymCost"/>  .. <xsl:value-of select="$selectNew"/>
                                    </td>
                                </xsl:if>  
                            </tr>
                        </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </table>    
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, that did the trick. But one question though, why do we need to use "OR" when we count the number of valid Service Nodes? I need both Amount Benefit to be greater than 0. But when I tested this on my sample XML, it actually works.

Comment: When you say you need both amounts to be greater than zero, then you should exclude all services that has at least 1 zero amount. In your desired output, you have included there the services which has at least 1 amount that is greater than zero.

Comment: In the $selectNew variable, we want to count only the amount greater than zero. And do not show any services that has zero amount and if both Current and Past 6 months has zero amount, then disregard that row altogether.

Comment: That is the function of the OR, it counts any row that has an amount greater than zero.

Answer (score 0):

Consider splitting your XSLT into several templates, one that styles the first *service* row and then *service* rows after first. This way you avoid the many `<xsl:if>` calls. Also, use parameters to pass needed values from above nodes:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="html"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/services">
    <html>
      <body>
        <table border="1" width="100%">
            <tr>
              <td style="text-align:center"> Name </td>
              <td style="text-align:center">Past 6 Months</td>
              <td style="text-align:center">Current 6 Months</td>
              <td style="text-align:center"> Gym </td>
            </tr>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="service[benefits[1]/amount &gt; 0 and benefits[1]/amount &gt; 0]">
                <xsl:with-param name="service_count">
                    <xsl:value-of select="count(*[benefits[1]/amount &gt; 0 or benefits[1]/amount &gt; 0])"/>
                </xsl:with-param>
                <xsl:with-param name="gym_amount">
                    <xsl:value-of select="service[name='Gym']/benefits/amount"/>
                </xsl:with-param>
            </xsl:apply-templates>

        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="service[1]">
    <xsl:param name="service_count"/>
    <xsl:param name="gym_amount"/>
    <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="name"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="benefits[period = 'Previous 6 months']/amount"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="benefits[period = 'Current 6 months']/amount"/></td>
        <td rowspan='{$service_count}'>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat($gym_amount, '...', $service_count)"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="service[position() &gt; 1]">
    <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="name"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="benefits[period = 'Previous 6 months']/amount"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="benefits[period = 'Current 6 months']/amount"/></td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

[image: XSLT Output Screenshot]